# Can't build NRPE on SLES 11 with SSL support

Tags: linux, openssl, autotools, nrpe, sles

I face issues with NRPE installation on SLES 11 SP3. I cant build NRPE on SLES. When i try to run the installation with `./configure` it setup starts however it fails with following error:

```
checking for SSL libraries... configure: error: Cannot find ssl libraries
```

Following version of openssl is installed, openssl 0.9.8j

Following workaround also don't help

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I understand that the openssl-devel is required for the NRPE installation, however I'm unable to find the devel package with would fit the already installed version of openssl.

Only devel package which i was able to find is version which is much never 1.xx, however this will require to update/reinstall openssl and all the dependencies and as the server is not using any package management tool and its not connected to the internet updating openssl with all its dependencies will be huge pain.

Any easy solution or workaround for this?

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.8 is too old to be useful. It was EOL years ago. Some configuration programs skip it or fail to find functions it looks for, like functions from OpenSSL 1.0.1 or OpenSSL 1.0.2. How is it a modern SUSE server is supplying OpenSSL 0.9.8?

Comment: *"Any easy solution or workaround for this"* - Install OpenSSL 1.0.2 in `/usr/local`. Your configure line will look something like `--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl`. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.